# Why LoadLibrary not working with the given path?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call `LoadLibrary` method, But it returns 0. `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` is returning 126 (The specified module could not be found.).

Code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);

string path = @"C:\junk\测试\BlueStacksKK_DeployTool_2.5.48.7209_china_gmgr\ProgramFiles\BstkC.dll";
IntPtr ptr = LoadLibrary(path);
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

But If I move this file to some other location like `C:\Test\BstkC.dll`, it works fine.

Issue could be due to `测试` in path. So If we have direcotry in other languages other then English, how will it work.

Just for your information. `File.Exists(path)` returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpFileName);
```

The underlying Win32 API comes with two flavors: ASCII mode (which allows only ASCII characters in strings) and Unicode Mode (which allows UTF16 characters in strings).

C# is UTF16 based, basically, you invoked a ASCII-flavored function with UTF16 string, you need to explicitly tell the CLR you want the Unicode flavored function (`LoadLibraryW`) and retain the UTF16 encoding of the C# string (by using  `LPWStr`).

Comment: Note that ASCII != ANSI.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the character set used to Unicode, since you use non-unicode character in your path:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
```

Now it takes the `LoadLibraryA` (ANSI) variant. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Sorry, omitting the `LPStr` is required too.